# SQL Query Issue, filtering rows based on result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have following result set from a query

```
Team    User  
PBC     BEI02 
ZTeam   BEI02 
PBC     HPP02
```

I need to extend the query so that outputs user **HPP02 only**.  Anyone that belong to ZTeam shouldn't be listed.

I guess, my issue is there are 1000's of records.  HPP02 is one of the results there are many users like HPP02, need to list them all.  Can't use where user = 'HPP02'.

Any idea how this can be achieved.

Thanks :)

Comment: Wouldn't a [`WHERE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx) clause work?  Am I missing something?

Comment: So we should extend a query we cannot see?

Comment: -1....crazy homework question; type `WHERE` and press F1

Answer (score 2):

In order for us to help you in the future, you should show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

```
SELECT Team, [User]
FROM unicorns
WHERE Team <> 'ZTeam' AND [User] = 'HPP02'
```

Comment: I guess, my issue is there are 1000's of records.  HPP02 is one of the results there are many users like HPP02, need to list them all.  Can't use where user = 'HPP02'. Thanks

Comment: @Kris1511 Then please update your question providing more information and vote to reopen.